# Diffie Hellman JavaCard

Tags: java, javacard, diffie-hellman

I have a problem with DiffieHellman on JavaCard. I have this class:
https://pastebin.com/2F2sQ2Pe (https://github.com/ASKGLab/DHApplet) ( its bigger file so I uplouded to pastebin not sure if its a problem )

And then I create 2 instance of it and call it like this ( show only one instance ):

```
DiffieHellman dh = new DiffieHellman();
dh.init();
dh.getY(hostY, (short)0);
dh.setY(cardY, (short) 0, (short) cardY.length, (short) 0); 
AESKey encKey = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES_TRANSIENT_RESET, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
dh.doFinal(encKey);
```

hostY and cardY are public values. I tried it on desktop App so I have guarance that there is no probleme with Communication with JavaCard. So my question is that after all of this SharedSecret differ and I have no idea why because I execute Y = G^bobPrivKey mod P via RSA's decrypt to get Y's transfer them and then execute S = Y^a mod p via RSA's decrypt.

Thank's for any answer in advance.

Comment: Eh, may we assume that 2048 bit DH is not available on your card implementation?

Comment: I tried it on desktop ( even without card )

Comment: Are you using [jCardSim](https://jcardsim.org/) to simulate javacard API on desktop? Or something else?

Comment: This is your code on the PC side, can you offer the code of the javacard applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you are using [jCardSim](https://jcardsim.org/) for Java Card API emulation on desktop)

There is a problem with jCardSim that it always uses CRT private keys (as used `RSAKeyPairGenerator` always generates CRT private keys which always implement `RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters` -- see [here](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim/blob/jc2.2.1/src/main/java/com/licel/jcardsim/crypto/KeyPairImpl.java#L260) and [here](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim/blob/jc2.2.1/src/main/java/com/licel/jcardsim/crypto/KeyPairImpl.java#L111)).

So every jCardSim RSA private key (even that generated with `ALG_RSA`) is implemented by `RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl` (you can check yourself with `.getClass().getCanonicalName()`).

The real problem is that `RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl` class ignores the value of modulus when doing the actual crypto:

[AssymetricCipherImpl.init()](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim/blob/jc2.2.1/src/main/java/com/licel/jcardsim/crypto/AssymetricCipherImpl.java#L71):

```
// ...some code above skipped...
KeyWithParameters key = (KeyWithParameters) theKey;
engine.init(theMode == MODE_ENCRYPT, key.getParameters());
// ...some code below skipped...
```

[RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.getParameters()](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim/blob/jc2.2.1/src/main/java/com/licel/jcardsim/crypto/RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java#L121) -- there is no use of `modulus` field:

```
public CipherParameters getParameters() {
    if (!isInitialized()) {
        CryptoException.throwIt(CryptoException.UNINITIALIZED_KEY);
    }
    // modulus = p * q;
    return new RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters(p.getBigInteger().multiply(q.getBigInteger()), null,
            null, p.getBigInteger(), q.getBigInteger(),
            dp1.getBigInteger(), dq1.getBigInteger(), pq.getBigInteger());
}
```

So the [`setModulus()` call](https://github.com/ASKGLab/DHApplet/blob/5f335a7acad82edb35f2f96cf3c89ac559d094a3/src/dhapplet/DH.java#L191) used to set the desired DH Group prime has no effect and the original (generated) modulus is used.

Good luck!